# How to center the editor window back on the cursor in VSCode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I'm using VSCode as my text editor. I'm curious, is there a keybinding for centering the editor window on the cursor, when the window is a lot of lines below/above it such that it's not visible on the screen? I've tried looking at the default keybindings by going to *FIle > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*, but I see no such options for centering the window.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is no such keybinding / command built-in.

I couldn't stand that either, so I created a VSCode extension. You can find it and install it [here on the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaiwood.center-editor-window). The default shortcut is `CTRL` + `L`.

Comment: is there such a plugin such that the screen is *always* centered on the cursor? I use vim as my primary text editor and I'm hoping VScode has similar functionality to this

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But sounds like an interesting extension to build. 

Comment: In that case it might be the first extension *I* build, haha

Comment: This is great! Why don't you implement it in the editor itself. To me, this looks like something that the editor by default show can benefit from. Just a thought.

Comment: @DanielSantos unfortunately VSCode is full of illogical choices for default settings, or in this case lack of them.

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen have you made the extension, I'm trying to find an extension that will always center the cursor on the screen.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to always keep the cursor on the center, you can change the setting `editor.cursorSurroundingLines` to a really high number (100 is ok) and that should work.

Comment: Great tip; no plugin required!

Comment: How is that not the accepted answer?

Comment: Great one! So helpful, why VS Code use 0 as surrounding lines ?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using vscodevim, `zz` should work.

Answer (score 3):

As @kwood put it, there is an extension [Center Editor Window](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaiwood.center-editor-window) in the marketplace that meets this end.

I would like to make an answer here, to complement that -- even the extension's author did not explicitly state in the marketplace page -- if you would like to change the default key binding (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), you may try put the following lines in the `keybindings.json` for the keyboard bindings.

```
{
    "key": "cmd+k cmd+c",
    "command": "center-editor-window.center",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

The above command sets <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut.

---

Apart from that, you may set

```
"center-editor-window.threeStateToggle": true,
```

in the `settings.json` for VS Code settings so that it will switch among three states (center, top, bottom) instead of one (center).